# how to to execute a command output as an argument without saving it using $()?

Tags: bash, command-line, macos

This is actually for `brew search`

but to simplify, let's say I do:

```
echo -e 'somedir\n\otherdir'
somedir
otherdir
```

Can I use `otherdir` as an argument  without doing this?

```
ls $(echo -e 'somedir\n\otherdir |tail -n1)
otherdir
```

#### Update to Clarify Goal

To be more clear `somedir` and `otherdir` go to stdout, can I run a command on only `otherdir`

Without capturing the output in  `$()`, then executing the command on that?

I just wanted to know if it's possible, although I think it can't be done.

Comment: Can you better clarify what your goal is?

Comment: clarified in update

Comment: You have to capture the output, that's what `$()` is meant for. Also you better double quote the `$()` to avoid shell splitting.

Comment: I already know that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `xargs` which is intended for this kind of thing: convert output streams to list of arguments:

```
printf 'somedir\n\otherdir\n' |
  tail -n1 |
  xargs -rd '\n' ls -l --
```

Beware `-d '\n'`, needed here for arguments to be expected as lines requires the GNU implementation of `xargs`.

If that last line doesn't contain blanks nor quotes nor backslashes, you can omit it.

`-r`, needed to avoid running `ls` if the input is empty is also from GNU `xargs` but  nowadays widely supported (and will be in the next version of the POSIX standard).

---

If you don't want to use command substitution, in `bash`, you can always read the lines of the output of the command into an array and run the command on the last element of that array:

```
readarray -t lines < <(printf 'somedir\notherdir\n')
if (( ${#lines[@]} > 0 )); then
  ls -l -- "${line[@]: -1}"
fi
```

Or use `perl`:

```
printf 'somedir\notherdir\n' |
  perl -lne 'exec qw(ls -l --), $_ if eof && $.'
```

---

Note that with command substitution, since it strips all trailing newline characters, you can't directly differentiate between an empty input and the last line being empty. In both cases, you get and empty expansion.

One advantage of using command substitution, is that you can check whether the command has succeeded (based on its exit status) before deciding to use its output:

```
die() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf>&2 '%s\n' "$@"; exit 1; }

last_line=$(
  set -o pipefail
  cmd | tail -n 1
) || die "cmd failed"

ls -l -- "$last_line"
```

Or you can use `grep` to also check that the output is non-empty:

```
if
  last_line=$(
    set -o pipefail
    cmd |
      tail -n 1 |
      grep '^'
  )
then
  ls -l -- "$last_line"
else
  echo>&2 "Either cmd failed or it didn't produce any output"
fi
```

`grep '^'` matches on the beginning of a line. So it will return true if the output contains at least one line (whether it's empty or not). Beware though that if the input doesn't end in a newline character, it's not considered as a line as per the POSIX definition of a line, and some `grep` implementations could fail in that case and even discard that non-delimited line.

Comment: thank you, finally someone with an alternative, always the best from you. Although I will stick with `$()` as it's simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `$()` doesn't *save* anything.  It basically means "run this command and use the output as arguments".

Your usage is the correct canonical way of doing things.

In older shells (and it still works) the backtick (`) does a similar thing

But `$()` is the modern way and also fixes a lot of hairy quoting problems the old way has.

This can be used almost anywhere;
eg

```
echo "The current time is: $(date)"
The current time is: Tue Nov 21 22:57:41 EST 2023
```

Comment: You still need to double quote it if you need to pass it as a single argument though (which is not the case in the `echo` example above).

Comment: forget the 'intricacies' and details. All I wanted to know is can I do can I do what $() does in this situation without using $()? or using the output of it? A way to get `otherdir` from the output of the `echo` command? You haven't answered my question and instead just corrected my wording of $() it can also be used in a variable  in which it would be 'saved' perhaps that's how I should have asked the question. I wasn't asking how $() is used or what it is which is what you answered

Comment: many thanks @TomYan for supplying that obscure information, I wish I had known that!

Comment: furthermore I don't think it's possible but I wanted to know if there is a way.

Comment: to be more clear `somedir` and `otherdir` go to stdout, can I run a command on `otherdir` without using $()?

Comment: `$(...)` is the ksh (and now POSIX sh so recognised by all POSIX-like shells) syntax (also in very recent versions of `fish`), `\`...\`` the Bourne and csh syntax, `\`{...}` the `rc`/`es`/`akanga` syntax. `(...)` the fish syntax.